# Needing some assistance with EA

Tags: quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, forex

I'm trying to code this logic:

> **`if`** `no open orders` **`and`** `buy logic ( DayOpen - 10 * Point )`
> **`then`** `buy`
>
> **`if`** `bought`
> `Sell` **`when`** `the one` (and the only one) `bought order reaches Take Profit price.`

---

Here's what I have so far:

```
double DayOpen = iOpen( NULL, PERIOD_D1, 0 );
double TP      = 10.0;
int    ticket;

if ( OrdersTotal() == 0 && Bid == DayOpen - 10 * Point );
{    OrderSend( Symbol(),
                OP_BUY,
                1.0,
                Ask,
                0,
                0,
                Ask + TP * 10 * Point,
                NULL,
                12321,
                0,
                Blue
                );
}
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

### Prologue
 <sup>( would be fine to [follow StackOverflow emphasis on posting a **complete** `M.C.V.E.`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) )</sup>

The code ought to read at least as syntactically-correct:

```
{                                                     // outer context missing
// .                                                  // outer context missing
// ..                                                 // outer context missing
// ...                                                // outer context missing
   RefreshRates();     // a life-saving jacket while  // outer context missing

   if (  OrdersTotal() == 0
      && Bid           <= iOpen( _Symbol, PERIOD_D1, 0 )
                        - ( 10 * _Point )
      )
   {  OrderSend( _Symbol,                            // <symbol>
                 OP_BUY,                             // <op> 
                 1.0,                                // <volume>
                 Ask,                                // <XTO_price>
                 0,                                  // <slippage_allowed>
                 0,                                  // <autoXTO_SL>
                 NormalizeDouble( Ask + 10 * _Point, // **ALWAYS**
                                  _Digits            // NORMALIZE XTO levels
                                  ),                 // <autoXTO_TP>
                 NULL,                               // <commentSTRING>
                 12321,                              // <MagNUM>
                 0,                                  // <expireSECONDs>
                 clrBlue                             // <arrowCOLOR>
                 );
   }

// ...
// ..
// .

}
```

### Epilogue

There is no need to add any additional constructs for the given logic. <kbd>**`MetaTrader Terminal 4`**</kbd> will dispatch the **`OrderSend()`** details to the remote <kbd>**`MetaTrader 4 Server`**</kbd> and if your values do meet the Broker-side **Terms & Conditions**, you will get such trading position opened ( exposed to Market Risk, while being fully backed & covered by your Equity ).

At the same time, the <kbd>`MetaTrader 4` **`Server`**</kbd> will ensure, that no other code is required per-se for such position to become **`<autoXTO_TP>`**-terminated on the very moment the FX-Market reaches the predefined `TP`-termination level.

While the above is true, it is however fair to say that professional-grade algo-trading systems have many other utility-services, attached to the core trading logic. Just to have some idea, designs with about 80.000 ~ 100.000 `SLOC`s are common in production-grade systems.

---

### Where to go from here?

It might be helpfull to **re-read** the **`MQL4` documentation**  <sub>( let me put this a bit clearer -- the **localhost-installed** and updated release of the ***actual-release-of***-*New*-`MQL4` language ... not the static and "old" texts on web, as the syntax-rules & context-specific limits creep a lot ... still do, ref. below )</sub> 
**rather
than**
 to headbang again into another issues with "old"-`MQL4` syntax code-snippets.

The `MQL4` language evolves a lot during the last few years and lot of web-posted code-snippets have lost their explanatory value, due to many shifts in paradigm, that happened "inside the language" or due to code-execution platform **changes**.

**Bitter?** Yes.
**Painfull?** Yes.

This is **the Life**, nevertheless...

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume that you've got the first part (opening a trade) of your logic right. Now you want all orders get closed when one of them reaches TP. Here is how you can do that.

Add this to `start()` function:

```
int total = OrdersHistoryTotal();
for (int i = total - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY) == false)
    {
        Print("Error selecting order from history: ", GetLastError());
        break;
    }
    if ((OrderSymbol() != Symbol()) || (OrderType() != OP_BUY) || (OrderClosePrice() < OrderTakeProfit())) continue;
    CloseAll();
    break;
}
```

And this outside the `start()` function:

```
void CloseAll()
{
   int total = OrdersTotal();
   for (int i = total - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      if (OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS) == false) continue;
      if ((OrderSymbol() != Symbol()) || (OrderType() != OP_BUY)) continue;
      RefreshRates();
      OrderClose(OrderTicket(), OrderLots(), Bid, Slippage);
   }
}
```

Comment: You might want to update your answer, @Enivid. The code is wrong both in the first assumption on correctness of opening a position, and in the second part, about a code-driven closing of "all" trades } when there is **`{ 0 | 1 }`** trade position managed ( `0` effectively, until the syntax of the first part finally gets corrected ).

Comment: You might next time also better review your own code, so as to **avoid syntax errors from being posted in an education-motivated answer** and better reflect the OP context-of-use ( as an example, you have forgotten to include an explicit **`OrderMagicNumber()`** check in the copied snippet code-logic ).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm still lost though. I want it to only open one order at a time and close when the buy orders' take profit is reached and when the conditions are met again it opens another one order. I acknowledge that system might not be profitable but I want to test it. So can you show me what that would look like so I can test it in the strategy tester. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rob, you need not "add" anything in order to run an MT4 Back-tester. Read carefully through the other answer and just polish the syntax ( erase colon **`;`** inside an **`if(...){...}`** condition-part of the constructor ( *inside/right after the first pair of parentheses* ) and run the code inside `OnTick(){...}`. It is that simple.

Comment: @Rob you may already know, that MT4-code-IDE ( aka MetaEditor ) can help you lot with syntax-highlighting, parenthesis-matching and online-help access, if you configure it to become a bit more handy for the language exploration. **Did you try, Rob, to tweak it a bit to fit your preferences?** You will, after some practice, realise, there are a few errors even in the MQL4 Reference / Help, that do not work straight on copy/paste, but anyway **do not hesitate to experiment a lot with the code inside MetaEditor.**